# Open another storyboard with tabbar and navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I'm creating a welcome page in an another storyboard 
I also have a skip button that should open the main storyboard

in the main storyboard, there is a minTabbar and every tab has its own navigation bar

here is my code in the acton of the skip button

```
var window: UIWindow?
let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

@IBAction func skipButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let todoTabBar = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainTabBar") as! UITabBarController
    todoTabBar.selectedIndex = 1
    let nvc = todoTabBar.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController
    nvc?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
}
```

but it's not working and nothing happen after tapping on the button, could you help me on that?
Thank you so much

Comment: Is there some error which you can share with us?

Comment: Just nothing happen after tapping on the skip button

Answer (score 0):

This

```
let nvc = todoTabBar.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController
nvc?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
```

plays with a vc that isn't currently displayed/presented so all actions will be on the fly , make sure to access the real presented 1 or show `todoTabBar` if that the case

---

If you need to leave the presenting vc do

```
self.present(todoTabBar,animated:true,completion:nil)
```

if you need to make `todoTabBar` the only presented 1 do

```
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window!.rootViewController = todoTabBar
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but i couldn't understand what should i do now

Comment: what your current code should do ? is that to show the tabBar or to modify a presented 1

Comment: yes it should open the main storyboard and the maintabar with selectedIndex = 1

Comment: so do `self.present(todoTabBar,animated:true,completion:nil)`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the root view controller fo window using following code:

```
    let stotyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "OtherStoryBoard", bundle: nil)
    if let otherVC = stotyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OtherViewController") 
    as? OtherViewController {

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = otherVC
        otherVC.selectedIndex = 0
        appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

Also looks like [@Sh_khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5820010/sh-khan) has provided you the solution as part of comments. Please accept that answer.